# Chips in angular with bootstrap with no material dependency

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, ngx-chips

**Details**:
Angular v9
Bootstrap 4
@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap v5.2.1

I tried [ngx-chips](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips), but it is dependent on angular material. And my project is using bootstrap.
For now I am using [ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/tags) with tags.
Can anyone suggest some other option?

Comment: Facing the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: You can check this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips#:~:text=tag%2Dinput%2Ddropdown%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)%3B-,Built%2Din%20Themes,-If%20you%20don%27t